# "Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers" doesn't have Java Script project

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I downloaded "Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers" for my windows 64-bit from the below link.
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-06/r/eclipse-ide-web-and-javascript-developers

I tried to create java script project (New-->Project-->Java script project) but couldn't find java script details in the wizard window. No luck even after installing java script related plugins.

Could someone let me know if I missed anything while installing or plugins to install ?

[Eclipse wizard window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/494du.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, as with non-IDE editors like VSCode, you don't need a special project type for working with JavaScript any more. Go do what you were going to do to make your application or script, and just remember to open your JavaScript files with the Generic Text Editor (if they don't already).

Comment: So, can I use Java project type in Eclipse and create my  js files inside it ? @nitind

Comment: Yes. (filler for SO)